# How to fix MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart-isolates

I need to use `path_provider` inside a `ForegroundService` packet. By the way the `Foreground Service` has `Isolate`, so I need to use `path_provider` inside `Isolate`. However, when I use it I have this exception:

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method
> getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel
> plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

My code:

```
void maybeStartFGS() async {
    ///if the app was killed+relaunched, this function will be executed again
    ///but if the foreground service stayed alive,
    ///this does not need to be re-done

    if (!(await ForegroundService.foregroundServiceIsStarted())) {
      await ForegroundService.setServiceIntervalSeconds(5);

      //necessity of editMode is dubious (see function comments)

      await ForegroundService.notification.startEditMode();
      await ForegroundService.notification
          .setTitle("Example Title: ${DateTime.now()}");
      await ForegroundService.notification
          .setText("Example Text: ${DateTime.now()}");

      await ForegroundService.notification.finishEditMode();

      await ForegroundService.startForegroundService(foregroundServiceFunction);
      await ForegroundService.getWakeLock();
    }

    ///this exists solely in the main app/isolate,
    ///so needs to be redone after every app kill+relaunch
    await ForegroundService.setupIsolateCommunication((data) {
      debugPrint("main received: $data");
     // _beacon.Brodcast();
      //_scanningBeacon.initScanBeacon();
    });
  }

  void foregroundServiceFunction() {

     debugPrint("The current time is: ${DateTime.now()}");
Future<List> readCounter() async {

    try {
      final file = await _localFile;
      print('file$file');
    // Read the file.
   List  reada = await  jsonDecode(file.readAsStringSync());
   print('reada$reada');
    return reada;
    } catch (e) {
print(e.toString());
    return null;
    }
    }
    ForegroundService.notification.setText("The time was: ${DateTime.now()}");

    if (!ForegroundService.isIsolateCommunicationSetup) {
      ForegroundService.setupIsolateCommunication((data) {
        debugPrint("bg isolate received: $data");

      });
    }
    ForegroundService.sendToPort("message from bg isolate");
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem with path_provider package like what you are facing right now, I did these steps to fixed it :

1. Delete/Uncomment package "path_provider" in pubspec.yaml
2. flutter pub run on terminal
3. Invalidate cache & restart android studio
4. Uncomment or add package "path_provider" in pubspec.yaml again.
5. do flutter pub run on terminal again.

Problem is fixed.

Answer (score -2):

Run `flutter clean` and `flutter run` again. This should fix the problem.